# Combine two arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is the multidimensional array I have(first array)

```
 Array( [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 56
            [heading] => 'w'
            [content] => Abcdefghijk 
        )
      .................

)
```

and the second array

```
Array
(
    [w] => 2
    [e] => 2
    [d] => 2
    ..

)
```

In the output I want to combine First array with second array only if the value of heading exists in the second array as an **index**.
Also the value of that index should be stored under the index -score.

```
Array( [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 56
            [heading] => 'w'
            [content] => Abcdefghijk 
            [score]=>2
        )
     ......

 )
```

Comment: Which `2` do you want?

Comment: how do you want to achieve a score ? what you want to do with the second array... just take the first or second or third value... or what...

Comment: from where `score` comes in ?

Comment: guess the answere is right :)

Comment: `$score = $scores[$array[1]['heading']]; $array[1]['score'] = $score;` — [Demo](https://eval.in/147035).

Comment: Yes score is the key and the value comes from second array

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the question, but I assume you want to get `heading` as `score`. Well then.

```
foreach ($frist as $key => $value) {
    $frist[$key]['score'] = $second[$value['heading']];
}
```

Comment: since i read this post.. it makes sense :D